# How to declare a stored procedure with one input variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this table (named Sandbox):

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | statecode | country |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | ITA       | Italy   |
|  2 | ESP       | Spain   |
|  3 | GER       | Germany |
|  4 | ESP       | Espana  |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure which gives me all the country names from one parameter (the statecode).

For example

```
CALL GetCountryNameFromCode('ITA');
```

should return "Italy"

```
CALL GetCountryNameFromCode('ESP');
```

should return "Spain", "Espana"

Following [this guide](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx) I wrote the following code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCountryNameFromCode (IN MyStateCode varchar(3))
BEGIN
    SELECT country
    FROM Sandbox
    WHERE statecode = MyStateCode
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I execute it, the phpMyAdmin gives me the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 6

what's wrong with my code? 
I am running the MySQL version 5.6.30 - Source distribution (AMPPS on MacOS)

============================== EDIT ==============================

Now I am running this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCountryNameFromCode (IN MyStateCode varchar(3))
BEGIN
    SELECT country
    FROM Sandbox
    WHERE statecode = MyStateCode;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

which gives me the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Despite the error message the SP is been created and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a semicolon after the end of the select statement to indicate the end of the statement and need to remove the semicolon after the `end` keyword because `//` terminates the stored proc's code.

See mysql manual on [defining stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) for details.

Comment: I modified the code with all your answers and now it works. The strange fact is that it still gives me an error message while I execute the code to create it. I post the code I used to create the SP up in the first question.

Answer (score 1):

First the column in your table is "county" not "country".
Second, you need to put a ; after your where clause:

```
WHERE statecode = MyStateCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetCountryNameFromCode` $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCountryNameFromCode`(IN MyStateCode varchar(3))
        BEGIN

       SELECT country
       FROM Sandbox
       WHERE statecode = MyStateCode;

        END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```